# Ajax with multiple forms

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have a page with multiple forms.

In one of the form

```
    <h:form id="form1">
        <!-- ... -->
        <h:commandButton value="Form button1">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <!-- ... -->
    <h:form id="form2">
        <!-- ... -->
        <h:commandButton value="Form button2" />
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="form3">
        <!-- ... -->
        <h:commandButton value="Form button3" />
    </h:form>
```

When I submit button in form1, the buttons at form2 are not refreshed. The old states are still retained

We are using Mojarra 2.2.8 version

May I know if there is any fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify what exactly you want to render in .

e.g.

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <!-- ... -->
    <h:commandButton value="Form button1">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":form2 :form3" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Hope it helps